# Terraform File provisioner can't connect ec2 over ssh. timeout - last error: dial tcp 92.242.xxx.xx:22: i/o timeout

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, terraform0.12+

I am using a terraform script to:
- Create a EC2 instance
- Use file provisioner to connect to the EC2 instance and copy a file
My Script is:

**Script**

```
provider "aws" {
  region = "us-east-1"
  shared_credentials_file = "~/.aws/credentials"
}

resource "aws_instance" "pd_terraform" {
  ami = "ami-03d315ad33b9d49c4"
  instance_type = "t2.micro"
  key_name = "pd_kp_tf"

  connection {
        type        = "ssh"
        host        = "${self.public_ip}.compute-1.amazonaws.com"
        user        = "ubuntu"
        private_key = "${file("~/.ssh/id_rsa")}"
    }

  provisioner "file" {

    content     = "touch pd_bash_file.txt"
    destination = "/tmp/script.sh"
  }
}
```

**Steps to Run the Script:**

```
terraform init 
terraform apply
```

**Expected Output:** The code runs completely and copies file to the EC2

**Actual Result:**
I am able to see my TF code create an EC2 instance. However it fails to
connect over the SSH and copy the file to the EC2 instance.
I am getting this error at the end `Error: timeout - last error: dial tcp 92.242.140.21:22: i/o timeout`

**Logs:**
I started a log tracing that has this block repeating:

```
file-provisioner (internal) 2021/03/03 12:44:55 [DEBUG] Connecting to 3.85.141.254.compute-1.amazonaws.com:22 for SSH
    2021/03/03 12:45:00 [TRACE] dag/walk: vertex "root" is waiting for "meta.count-boundary (EachMode fixup)"
    2021/03/03 12:45:00 [TRACE] dag/walk: vertex "meta.count-boundary (EachMode fixup)" is waiting for "output.ip"
    2021/03/03 12:45:00 [TRACE] dag/walk: vertex "provisioner.file (close)" is waiting for "aws_instance.pd_terraform"
    2021/03/03 12:45:00 [TRACE] dag/walk: vertex "provider[\"registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws\"] (close)" is waiting for "aws_instance.pd_terraform"
    2021/03/03 12:45:00 [TRACE] dag/walk: vertex "output.ip" is waiting for "aws_instance.pd_terraform"
    2021/03/03 12:45:05 [TRACE] dag/walk: vertex "provider[\"registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws\"] (close)" is waiting for "aws_instance.pd_terraform"
    2021/03/03 12:45:05 [TRACE] dag/walk: vertex "meta.count-boundary (EachMode fixup)" is waiting for "output.ip"
    2021/03/03 12:45:05 [TRACE] dag/walk: vertex "provisioner.file (close)" is waiting for "aws_instance.pd_terraform"
    2021/03/03 12:45:05 [TRACE] dag/walk: vertex "output.ip" is waiting for "aws_instance.pd_terraform"
    2021/03/03 12:45:05 [TRACE] dag/walk: vertex "root" is waiting for "meta.count-boundary (EachMode fixup)"
    2021/03/03 12:45:10 [TRACE] dag/walk: vertex "root" is waiting for "meta.count-boundary (EachMode fixup)"
    2021/03/03 12:45:10 [TRACE] dag/walk: vertex "output.ip" is waiting for "aws_instance.pd_terraform"
    2021/03/03 12:45:10 [TRACE] dag/walk: vertex "provisioner.file (close)" is waiting for "aws_instance.pd_terraform"
    2021/03/03 12:45:10 [TRACE] dag/walk: vertex "provider[\"registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws\"] (close)" is waiting for "aws_instance.pd_terraform"
    2021/03/03 12:45:10 [TRACE] dag/walk: vertex "meta.count-boundary (EachMode fixup)" is waiting for "output.ip"
    file-provisioner (internal) 2021/03/03 12:45:10 [ERROR] connection error: dial tcp 92.242.140.21:22: i/o timeout
    file-provisioner (internal) 2021/03/03 12:45:10 [WARN] retryable error: dial tcp 92.242.140.21:22: i/o timeout
    file-provisioner (internal) 2021/03/03 12:45:10 [INFO] sleeping for 20s
    2021/03/03 12:45:15 [TRACE] dag/walk: vertex "meta.count-boundary (EachMode fixup)" is waiting for "output.ip"
    2021/03/03 12:45:15 [TRACE] dag/walk: vertex "output.ip" is waiting for "aws_instance.pd_terraform"
    2021/03/03 12:45:15 [TRACE] dag/walk: vertex "provisioner.file (close)" is waiting for "aws_instance.pd_terraform"
    2021/03/03 12:45:15 [TRACE] dag/walk: vertex "provider[\"registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws\"] (close)" is waiting for "aws_instance.pd_terraform"
    2021/03/03 12:45:15 [TRACE] dag/walk: vertex "root" is waiting for "meta.count-boundary (EachMode fixup)"
    2021/03/03 12:45:20 [TRACE] dag/walk: vertex "meta.count-boundary (EachMode fixup)" is waiting for "output.ip"
    2021/03/03 12:45:20 [TRACE] dag/walk: vertex "output.ip" is waiting for "aws_instance.pd_terraform"
    2021/03/03 12:45:20 [TRACE] dag/walk: vertex "provisioner.file (close)" is waiting for "aws_instance.pd_terraform"
    2021/03/03 12:45:20 [TRACE] dag/walk: vertex "provider[\"registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws\"] (close)" is waiting for "aws_instance.pd_terraform"
    2021/03/03 12:45:20 [TRACE] dag/walk: vertex "root" is waiting for "meta.count-boundary (EachMode fixup)"
    2021/03/03 12:45:25 [TRACE] dag/walk: vertex "output.ip" is waiting for "aws_instance.pd_terraform"
    2021/03/03 12:45:25 [TRACE] dag/walk: vertex "root" is waiting for "meta.count-boundary (EachMode fixup)"
    2021/03/03 12:45:25 [TRACE] dag/walk: vertex "provisioner.file (close)" is waiting for "aws_instance.pd_terraform"
    2021/03/03 12:45:25 [TRACE] dag/walk: vertex "meta.count-boundary (EachMode fixup)" is waiting for "output.ip"
    2021/03/03 12:45:25 [TRACE] dag/walk: vertex "provider[\"registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws\"] (close)" is waiting for "aws_instance.pd_terraform"
    2021/03/03 12:45:30 [TRACE] dag/walk: vertex "provider[\"registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws\"] (close)" is waiting for "aws_instance.pd_terraform"
    2021/03/03 12:45:30 [TRACE] dag/walk: vertex "root" is waiting for "meta.count-boundary (EachMode fixup)"
    2021/03/03 12:45:30 [TRACE] dag/walk: vertex "provisioner.file (close)" is waiting for "aws_instance.pd_terraform"
    2021/03/03 12:45:30 [TRACE] dag/walk: vertex "output.ip" is waiting for "aws_instance.pd_terraform"
    2021/03/03 12:45:30 [TRACE] dag/walk: vertex "meta.count-boundary (EachMode fixup)" is waiting for "output.ip
```

Troubleshooting: I tried to connect using the same key to the ec2 instance created by terraform. I was able to connect without any problems. General discussion on various forums suggest that this could be a security groups related issue but since I am able to connect with my terminal it is unlikely.

Comment: What if you replace `"${self.public_ip}.compute-1.amazonaws.com"` with `self.public_ip`?

Comment: It didnt make a difference. I realized from the logs that the problem was not the name resolution. I also tried to create a output block at the end of main.tf to print the self.public_ip and it was able to show a FQDN. That still didnt solve the problem. I had to specifically create a Security Group as shown in my solution below that allows ingress traffic.

Comment: @pushd93 in the above code you shared you didnt specified security group still, but you also said this < this could be a security groups related issue but since I am able to connect with my terminal it is unlikely.>, so a gap here, I wonder how you were able to connect even when you didnt speficied any security group. As [vpc_security_group_ids](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/instance#vpc_security_group_ids) is optional, it didnt complained, while creating the resource.

Answer (score 3):

I found the solution to my problem in a github repo here: https://github.com/DeekshithSN/Terraform/blob/master/Provisioner/file-Provisioner/main.tf

I had to define a Security Group in my terraform main file. The updated main file is like:

```
    resource "aws_instance" "web" {
  ami           = "ami-04bf6dcdc9ab498ca"
  instance_type = "t2.micro"
  key_name      = "pd_kp_tf"
  user_data     = "${file("httpd.sh")}"
  vpc_security_group_ids = ["${aws_security_group.webSG.id}"]
  tags = {
    Name = "Test-file-provisioner"
  }

}

resource "null_resource" "copyhtml" {

    connection {
    type = "ssh"
    host = aws_instance.web.public_ip
    user = "ec2-user"
    private_key = file("pd_kp_tf.pem")
    }

  provisioner "file" {
    source      = "index.html"
    destination = "/tmp/index.html"
  }

  provisioner "file" {
    source      = "copy.sh"
    destination = "/tmp/copy.sh"
  }

  depends_on = [ aws_instance.web ]

  }

resource "aws_security_group" "webSG" {
  name        = "webSG"
  description = "Allow ssh  inbound traffic"

  ingress {
    from_port   = 22
    to_port     = 22
    protocol    = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }

  ingress {
    from_port   = 80
    to_port     = 80
    protocol    = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }

  egress {
    from_port       = 0
    to_port         = 0
    protocol        = "-1"
    cidr_blocks     = ["0.0.0.0/0"]

  }
}
```

I believe the ingress and egress blocks in the WebSG security group allow your instance to accept ssh traffic. You can also check his other provisioners in case you face any problems. I was able to run all the provisioners from his code.

**Resolution:**
Defining security group which allows ingress traffic on port 22 and 80.

Answer (score 1):

DNS name should be like this:

> ec2-xx-xx-xx-xx.compute-1.amazonaws.com

As you can see you need to do replacement of `.` with `-` char even when you `self.public_ip` if you wanna use DNS name, so it is good to use `self.public_ip`

```
resource "aws_instance" "pd_terraform" {
 ami = "ami-03d315ad33b9d49c4"
 instance_type = "t2.micro"
 key_name = "pd_kp_tf"

 connection {
       type        = "ssh"
       host        = self.public_ip
       user        = "ubuntu"
       private_key = "${file("~/.ssh/id_rsa")}"
   }

 provisioner "file" {

   content     = "touch pd_bash_file.txt"
   destination = "/tmp/script.sh"
 }
}
```

[self object](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/resources/provisioners/connection.html#the-self-object)